# Unsupported driver and OPEN GL problems

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, opengl

I'm trying to use an old computer with linux ubuntu 20.04.

Unfortunately my graphic card (ATI XPRESS 200m) is not well supported... the "radeon" open source drivers is buggued and most softwares hangs even simple ones....

Is there a way to install a better driver ?
Is there a way to complettly disable OPEN GL and use software emulation instead ?

Even glxinfo does segmentation fault !!!

Example:

```
glxinfo
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_no_config_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: X.Org R300 Project (0x1002)
    Device: ATI RS480 (0x5975)
    Version: 20.2.6
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 128MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: compat (0x2)
    Max core profile version: 0.0
    Max compat profile version: 2.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 2.0
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org R300 Project
OpenGL renderer string: ATI RS480
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 20.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_buffer_storage, 
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clip_control, 
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, 
    GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, 
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, 
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, GL_ARB_shader_image_size, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_include, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_sync, 
    GL_ARB_texture_barrier, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_ARB_texture_float, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_fragment_shader, GL_ATI_separate_stencil, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_EGL_sync, 
    GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_direct_state_access, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_subtexture, 
    GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, GL_EXT_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, 
    GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile, 
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr, 
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_pack_invert, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, 
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_image, 
    GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image, 
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays
**Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)**
```

Comment: If this is an old computer, you never gave any info. Does it support 20.04?

Comment: Acording to the web site that graphic card game out in Release date(s) November 8, 2004

Comment: Yes this is an old computer. LUnbuntu 20.04 installed perfectly well and runs fine, I can use the GUI, runs most softwares, like web browsers, gcompris, and so on... however some applications hangs like "glxinfo".

Comment: By the way: it used to work perfectly well with ubuntu 18.... include all the applications that now hangs ....

Comment: Your question says Ubuntu now you say Lubuntu a different more light weight OS. 20.04 has higher requirement then 18.04

Comment: AMD abandoned this product so their official driver is not going to help. Linux kernel needs to be 2.6.28 or lower. So no you will need to find another OS. Linux kernel 2.6.15 with ati drivers 8.20.8 will work flawlessly. I would suggest Gentoo with xorg 7.0. Ubuntu is not going to work

Comment: Actually I found a better solution to my problem: updated /etc/environment with LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1

Comment: This page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver indicates that RS480 firmware of the Radeon XPRESS 200 (m) is fully supported in version ubuntu 16.04+ and I can confirm it was in 16.04 ! However, this is no onger true in 20.04 !! Maybe this page needs updating ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this graphic card is too old, my worka around was:

Update file /etc/environment and add 2 lines

> LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1

> QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1

Now, the software I want to use run with software open gl only, and run fine.
Maybe slower although I did not even notice !

Answer (score 0):

This page help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver indicates that RS480 firmware of the Radeon XPRESS 200 (m) is fully supported in version ubuntu 16.04+ and I can confirm it was in 16.04 ! However, this is no onger true in 20.04 !! Maybe this page needs updating ???

Anyone that can do that ??? Clearly the supported has dropped somewhere between 16.04 and 20.04 versions....